# What is the most frequent scale degree?

Tags: theory, scales

Just as people have analyzed texts to determine letter frequency, what is the most frequent scale degree? (For typical pieces with a key signature). I'm looking for a count that's treats all note-values equally, e.g. one quarter note C and one half note C each count as one note.

The only thing that I found was https://www.hooktheory.com/blog/music-theory-analysis-1300-songs-for-songwriting-part2/ which only lists chords and doesn't have a direct a correspondence to scale degrees' frequency. What have been the results of such calculations in the past, if there have been any?

I don't have any particular genre in mind, though I realize that restricting to a certain body of music is necessary to conduct such an analysis. A possibility that comes to mind is https://abcnotation.com/tunes , as well as various MIDI datasets for e.g. classical music and jazz. Again, I don't really care what genre was chosen.

The reason I ask is because I am devising my own musical shorthand and would like to make the most frequent scale degrees the fastest to write.

Comment: The question is not well defined to me. What specifically do you ask about and for what purpose? Like which scale degree appears the most often in the melodies? Including passing tones or only those on downbeats? Treating beat 1 and 3 the same or not? What about the first note of the melody? It is often very significant. Finally, if better defined, that would perhaps make a good topic for a Master thesis, rather than SE answer.

Comment: There are "corpus" studies in music, where a large body of music is encoded in some way for musical elements - I've seen corpus studies of Roman numeral analysis, chords - and then various statistical analysis is done. The analysis I've seen is about frequency and "grammatical", bi-gram, tri-gram, how frequently one thing occurs after another.

Comment: Yet again, another good music theory question, closed. I know of only one corpus study, but it covers scale degrees in common practice and rock music sets, http://davidtemperley.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/temperley-declercq-jnmr.pdf, you may find other studies, but I don't know any - off the top of my head - about scale degrees.

Comment: @Michael - in it's original form this was not a good question here. The edit dramatically improves it, such that reopening seems reasonable.

Comment: I thought I voted to close this on the grounds that it was not clear, and commented on this thread.  Yet I see my comment deleted and the close vote seems locked.

Comment: I still suggest that since the scale degree of a particular note is context-dependent, this may be a very difficult question to answer. We could easily count the number of C4 notes in a MIDI data set, but it’s not easy to determine which scale degree those C4s are evoking at the moments they appear. Basing it on the key of the piece (when available) might give a baseline estimate, but doesn’t take into account modulations or keys of the moment, which is a particular problem in jazz. Also MIDI note numbers don’t distinguish between enharmonic equivalents, so what degree do they indicate?

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking about "degrees" like tonic, dominant, etc or frequencies like 440Hz etc.  We have a pretty good short hand (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).  You can't get much simpler than these and they are easy to write.  Since you want this to be genre agnostic I'd say it's an altogether inappropriate question since the results will necessarily be genre specific.  But, since keys are chosen based on abundance of notes I might guess that "1" is the most commonly encountered note in any key.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that's the point of a corpus study, it sets a context. The point is people are doing this so questions like this can be answered.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis That’s fair. But **we** can’t reasonably answer this question **here**. Teams of researchers and musicologists and ML programmers might be able to start answering this question and others like it, but just because it could potentially be answered someday doesn’t mean it’s a good fit for Music.SE today.

Comment: awe lotta, Why not find the answer to this question yourself? Are you hoping someone else has already found the answer?

Comment: Since the core idea is a rapid short-hand notation, the note-frequency issue can be obviated by using a notation where all symbols are equally quick to write. I recommend assigning a symbol to every pitch so that there's no question of how to notate modulations or chromatic alterations. If typing: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 t e] or [a s d f g h j k l ; t n]. If hand written: [(low dot) (high dot) (low circle) (high circle) | - / \ ( ) U ^].

Comment: I simply cannot understand why you need an order of most common down to least common scale degrees - which can't help any better than merely using 1-7 or whatever for the actual notes. Seems like re-inventing the wheel to me. And then you'll have the problem of how to write notes in other octaves.

Answer (score 3):

One initial comment: I don't really see the connection between the question "What is the most frequent scale degree?" and the purpose "devising my own musical shorthand and would like to make the most frequent scale degrees the fastest to write"

The standard I have seen for indicating scale degrees is a circumflex over the scale degree number...

[image]

...but it's hard to type that so I have seen the circumflex as a prefix, like `^1`.

Of course Roman numerals `I II III...` have the same scale degree meaning but that context is specifically to mean the degree is a chord root. The circumflex is usual for of a melodic context.

I don't think you necessarily need to know about the frequency of scale degree to take advantage of that scale degree notation for a quick short hand system. Maybe something like: `^5|G:^6 ^5 ^1|D7:^7...` for a sketch of chords, bars, and melody degrees.

But, if you want to look for objective info about frequency of scale degrees, try looking up *corpus* studies. That is where a researcher encodes a large corpus (body) of representative music for the researcher's interest and then does quantitative analysis on that data.

This one study came to mind immediately: [Temperly, de Clercq. Statistical Analysis of Harmony and Melody in Rock Music](http://davidtemperley.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/temperley-declercq-jnmr.pdf). It's a scholarly article so it describes their methods and the body of music used. It includes a few graphs like *Scale-degree distributions in common-practice music, rock harmony, and rock melody.* Spoiler alert: the authors come to this conclusion: *In all three, the most frequent scale-degree is 1, followed by 5.*

Comment: This literally does not answer the question.  It provides a shorthand for notating notes and intervals, which many comments do as well.  But where is the answer to the question "what notes are most frequent"?

Comment: @ggcg Perhaps you gave up on the answer before getting to the very last sentence: “ In all three, the most frequent scale-degree is 1, followed by 5.”

Comment: Since this is for writing out certain notes that will only translate to pitches in a certain key, using a circumflex seems a waste. What's wrong with pure numbers. And since 1 (root) will most likely be the most common, what could be easier to write than...1?

Comment: It does not answer the question.  It merely quotes one source and the op wanted a non genre related answer

Comment: @Tim. If it's a personal shorthand notation, the OP can do whatever they like. If numerals are used several ways, and existing convention to distinguish scale degree is a circumflex.

Comment: @ggcg. No. "non-genre" wasn't specified in the question. This "...I realize that restricting to a certain body of music is necessary..." is how the question was worded. And the study provides an answer from two bodies of music.

Comment: ...no comments on my shorthand tune? I was hoping to draw at least one comment :-)

Comment: "I don't have any particular genre in mind" stuck out more.

Comment: Which means any genre will do, it doesn't mean "non-genre", some kind of universal tonality. I'm not really sure what this issue is. The question was clear and the means of answering are too.